# A short story about artificial intelligence written by an author from Russia or Poland?

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence, stanislaw-lem

I once read an interesting short story about the possibility of a set of intelligent machines creating philosophy. Unfortunately I can't find the book that contains this short story. All I can remember it was an author from the so called Soviet bloc -- someone from the USSR or from Poland. Maybe Stanislaw Lem, or maybe the Strugatsky brothers.

It was a dispute between a philosopher and a computer scientist or a programmer.

Does anybody remember that?

Comment: Please don't [cross post](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/24879/58) to two different sites with the exact same question

Comment: It sounds the sort of thing Lem would have written. He is repeatedly critical of philosophers in his stories. However I have a pretty complete collection of Lem's work and I don't recall a story like this.

Comment: Sorry for crossposting, @Mithical. I didn't know it was not allowed.

Comment: I read this a long time ago, but unfortunately I can't find the book. I'm sure it was a short story collection, so maybe it was a less famous writer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be [**Bet**](https://www-rulit-me.translate.goog/books/vnimanie-ahi-read-121020-8.html?_x_tr_sl=ru&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=uk&_x_tr_pto=wapp) by [**Vladlen Bahnov**](https://ru-m-wikipedia-org.translate.goog/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD_%D0%95%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87?_x_tr_sl=ru&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=uk&_x_tr_pto=wapp) (published in 1970):

[image]

> So, dear cyberologist, - said the old philosopher, repeat, please, once again the conditions of our bet. Let's fix them in order
> to avoid further misunderstandings on magnetic tape. - With pleasure.
> The conditions are as follows: to conduct our experiment, we, dear
> philosopher, order a dozen machines that can create works of art...

> ...The machines were very happy about the discovery of a new genre and
> rushed to create critical masterpieces, furiously accusing each other
> of ignorance...

> ...What's the matter? We asked to make MUTs who would not know
> anything except the rules for creating works. - Right. But these MUTs
> know absolutely nothing. - Not true! These MUTs know they don't know
> anything. And Socrates did not know any more!

[Full text (google translate)](https://www-rulit-me.translate.goog/books/vnimanie-ahi-read-121020-8.html?_x_tr_sl=ru&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=uk&_x_tr_pto=wapp)

Comment: Great, Yaroslav !  That was precisely what I was looking for.

Большое спасибо !

Comment: You are welcome, будь ласка =)